# Sum of column values in a string matrix using numpy in python

Tags: python, string, numpy

l=["101","111","011"]
calculate sum of column values using numpy of string matrix
for i in range(k):
sum=0
for j in range(n):
sum+=int(s[j][i])

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be:

```py
>>> sum([int(x) for x in l])
223
```

If you want to use `numpy`:

```py
a = np.array(l).astype(int)
>>> a
array([101, 111,  11])

>>> a.sum()
223
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sum per column/position

```
l=["101","111","011"]
[sum(map(int, x)) for x in zip(*l)]
#[2, 2, 3]
```

Not that this is different from a classical `sum([int(x) for x in l])` if you reach a sum greater than 9:

```
l=["101","191","011"]

[sum(map(int, x)) for x in zip(*l)]
# [2, 10, 3]

sum([int(x) for x in l])
# 303
```